# Подскажите пожалуйста,правильно ли я подключаю ajax запрос в php файл

Tags: php, ajax

Есть файл `layout.php`. В нем, между тегами `<head>` корректно подключён `jquery.js` (рабочая ссылка в исходном коде). При подключении ajax-запроса в `layout.php`, на странице ничего не отображается. Подключаю так:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
function show(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/templates/tribune2/layouts/default/parser_mn.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#content").html(html);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    show();
    setInterval('show()',600000);
});
</script>
```

Пробовал url прописывать по разному, толку ноль.
Если указанный код вставить в html документ, то всё работает корректно.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

Comment: Что происходит в консоле браузера?

Comment: В консоле TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function

Comment: Похоже, Вы подключаете jQuery после того, как подключаете этот скрипт. Во всяком случае эта ошибка говорит о том, что браузер не знает переменной `$`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Проверьте, подключается ли *jQuery* вообще.
Для это загляните в код сформированной страницы:
`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `U` (Win/Lin),
`Alt` + `Cmd` + `U` (Mac)
И посмотрите, есть ли в коде строчки с подключением *jQuery*, и выше ли они исполняемого кода.

2.Если *jQuery* подключается, нужно знать нет ли у вас другой библиотеки, что переопределяет `$`.
Для этого достаточно сделать так:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
/* Закоментируйте временно ваш код */
if( typeof jQuery != 'undefined' ){
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
</script>
```

Если *jQuery* подключен в алерте будет версия библиотеки, что так же будет означать, что `$` переопределяет другая библиотека.
Если алерта не будет - означает, что *jQuery* вообще не подключен.

Comment: Да, появился алерт с версией библиотеки 1.11.3

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то алерт вывел версию другой Jquery-библиотеки? И если это верно,то мне нужно просто подключиться к ней, отключив последнюю?

Comment: `alert($.n.jquery);` - отдаст результат? Если нет, то в консоле тожна красоваться таже ошибка. Это будет означать, что кто то переопределяет `$`. Отключайте поочередно скрипты и определите кто.

Comment: После включения строки alert($.n.jquery); в код, косоль выдаёт: TypeError: $.n is undefined

Comment: Ищите кто пере определяет `$`.

Comment: Спасибо всем участвующим. Решил проблему кардинально. Прописал в php через фрейм, html-файл с подключенным jquery и с запросом ajax к файлу из url.

Comment: Единственная проблема-это не выводится в firefox.В webkit браузерах и осле, все работает. Но это уже другая история.

Comment: Не каждый браузер относится положительно к такой магии, кто то принимает и светлую сторону.

Comment: Тьфу ты, прошу прощения ....Всё норм! просто adblock'i видимо мешали и всякие firebag'i :). Отключил и заработало. Ещё раз-Огромное спасибо всем!!!

Comment: Не совсем понятно как и что вы у себя решили. Но если работает и вас это устраивает, то закрывайте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте для начала вторую функцию изменить на:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(show, 600000);
});
```

И напишите что после этого в консоли

Comment: Заменял функцию на функцию. Бестолку. И таж ошибка

Comment: Не вводите людей в заблуждение!! `setInterval` и `setTimeout` отрабатывают через промежуток времени. Ваш вариант предлагает сперва подождать 10минут. Вариант ТС подразумевает выполнить сразу и каждые 10 минут.

Comment: Ясно. Я подумал ТС ошибся

Answer (score -1):

Если success не срабатывает, добавь в $.ajax запрос еще

```
error:function(){
    console.log('Ошибка');
}
```

И если будет ошибка, значит ошибка либо в файле (пхп), либо в доступе к нему

Comment: А куда вставлять то код? Я не бумубум...

Comment: <div id="content"></div>
<script>
function show(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/templates/tribune2/layouts/default/parser_mn.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#content").html(html);
        },
       error: function(){
          console.log('Ошибка');
      }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    show();
    setInterval('show()',600000);
});
</script>

Comment: Нужно было добавить это в ответ.